# Gradle/TestNG : How to specify testng include group in build.gradle while using suiteXmlBuilder()?

Tags: gradle, testng

In build.gradle, I have specified the following configuration for TestNG tests execution.
What I want to do is: instead of specifying the method names, want to specify the testng group along with class. I need to specify the class for the expected execution sequence. At a package level or with just useTestNG() option, the execution sequence is different. Please help me how to do this.

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        suiteXmlBuilder().suite(name: 'Suite-Browser Tests', parallel: 'instances') {
            test(name: 'Test-Browser Tests') {
                classes([:]) {
                    'class'(name: 'com.XXX.classname') {
                        methods([:]) {
                            include(name: 'testMethod1')
                            include(name: 'testMethod2')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifed as below to include groups:

```
   test{
        useTestNG()
                {

                    suiteXmlBuilder().suite(name: 'Suite-Browser Tests', parallel: 'instances') {
                        test(name: 'Test-Browser Tests') {
                            groups([:]) {
                                run([:]){
                                    include(name: 'regression')
                                }
                            }
                            classes([:]) {
                                'class'(name: 'com.XXX.classname') {
                                    methods([:]) {
                                        include(name: 'testMethod1')
                                        include(name: 'testMethod2')
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
}
```

But after this, @BeforeClass in super class is not getting executed.
Also, the test report shows the @Test methods from other groups as well (all the tests are failed though as @BeforeClass is not executed).